# Pyspark Structured Streaming Json Schema

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark-sql, jsonschema, pyspark

How to create json schema required for spark structured streaming? 
Tried to generate using "from_json" But it's not compatible with pyspark.

I'm using spark version 2.3.0

Comment: Share your example code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method `from_json` requires that you provide the schema as `StructType([StructField(...)])` as its second argument. For your data-stream create a StructType schema and pass it to the function as `from_json(datastream,your_msg_schema)` and you should be golden.

If you need any specific help on the above case, please share the code that you have tried.